# Automatic selection of user when we create post in django restframework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

When I create a model, how do I ensure that the user can be selected as the user I am logged in to?

### model.py

```
class Advertise(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="ilan başlığı")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name="ilan 
     açıklaması")
```

### view.py##

```
class advertise(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AdvertiseMainSerializer
    queryset = Advertise.objects.all()
```

### serializer py##

```
class AdvertiseMainSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Advertise
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: how does your `Advertise` model look like?

Comment: sorry. I added. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the **`perform_create(...)`** method

```
class AdvertiseCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AdvertiseMainSerializer
    queryset = Advertise.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

**Note:**

I have changed the class name `advertise` to **`AdvertiseCreateAPIView`** since class names should normally use the **CapWords** convention as per the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) guide.